# goroutine asleep - deadlock

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

In the following code I am trying to spawn `MaxOutstanding` number of handlers. Each handler loops over items in the queue `queue` and prints them out, I also write `true` to the `done` channel.

In my main function, I start the handlers and write 9 elements to the `queue` and wait for the 1st element to be written to the `done` queue.

```
package main


import "fmt"

type Request struct {
        int32
}
var MaxOutstanding = 5
func handle(queue chan *Request, i int, done chan bool) {
    for r := range queue {
        fmt.Println(i, "---", r)
        done <- true
    }
}

func Serve(clientRequests chan *Request, quit, done chan bool) {
    // Start handlers
    for i := 0; i < MaxOutstanding; i++ {
        go handle(clientRequests, i, done)
    }
    <-quit  // Wait to be told to exit.
}


func main() {
    clientRequests := make(chan *Request)
    quit := make(chan bool)
    done := make(chan bool)

    go Serve(clientRequests, quit, done)

    clientRequests <- &Request{4}
    clientRequests <- &Request{1}
    clientRequests <- &Request{2}
    clientRequests <- &Request{3}

    clientRequests <- &Request{5}
    clientRequests <- &Request{6}
    clientRequests <- &Request{7}
    clientRequests <- &Request{8}
    clientRequests <- &Request{9}
    fmt.Println( "...........>", <- done )
    close(clientRequests)
    close(done)
}
```

On execution I get the following error. I don't see whats wrong with the implementation, I am even closing the channel.

```
4 --- &{4}
0 --- &{1}
1 --- &{2}
2 --- &{3}
3 --- &{5}
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
        /home/ubuntu/digs-svc/src/digs/go1.go:45 +0x251

goroutine 5 [chan receive]:
main.Serve(0xc82004c060, 0xc82004c0c0, 0xc82004c120)
        /home/ubuntu/digs-svc/src/digs/go1.go:28 +0x92
created by main.main
        /home/ubuntu/digs-svc/src/digs/go1.go:37 +0xb9

goroutine 6 [chan send]:
main.handle(0xc82004c060, 0x0, 0xc82004c120)
        /home/ubuntu/digs-svc/src/digs/go1.go:16 +0x23b
created by main.Serve
        /home/ubuntu/digs-svc/src/digs/go1.go:25 +0x5b
```

EDIT:

Apparently, the `fmt.Println("....", <- done)` wasn't enough to signify that there is a consumer to the `done` channel. I moved the code up in the execution order. A consumer needs to be "listening" on the channel when data is written to it. In my earlier code, the when the first data was written there were no consumer.

Working code.

https://play.golang.org/p/98l2M4XO9t

Comment: At first sight you write to `done` at least 5 times, but read from it only once.

Comment: @myaut , That is the intention. I am only interested in the first instance of data being written to done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blocking the iteration over the channel in your handle function with the send on the `done` channel, because nothing is receiving on the other side.

Those extra channels aren't really doing anything, and you could just add a `WaitGroup` to synchronize the handler's exit, then you can remove the `done` channel which will allow the handler to continue.

```
func handle(queue chan *Request, i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for r := range queue {
        fmt.Println(i, "---", r)
    }
}

func Serve(clientRequests chan *Request, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // Start handlers
    for i := 0; i < MaxOutstanding; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go handle(clientRequests, i, wg)

    }
}

func main() {
    clientRequests := make(chan *Request)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    go Serve(clientRequests, &wg)

    for i := int32(0); i < 50; i++ {
        clientRequests <- &Request{i}
    }

    close(clientRequests)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/oUFjZONjhk (note that in the playground, this example seems to currently favor a single goroutine being the receiver. Normally the blocked goroutines will receive randomly, and you can see that behavior if you compile and run normally)

Comment: Thanks for the answer with WaitGroup. I think that is a better solution to synchronize multiple goroutines.

Comment: "_because nothing is receiving on the other side_"

According to the code there was 1 line which was actually receiving data on the other side `fmt.Println( "...........>", <- done )`. I moved the line up in the execution order and it worked fine. I suppose a channel needs to have consumer while data is being written and not sometime in the future.

Comment: @Pratyush: yes, there was 1 receive, but you need to receive continuously to keep those for loops going.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the for loop you are handling the channel operation only to the 5th element, however in the main function you are trying to send over the value to the channel, which is closed.

To overcome this situation you can send the request value inside a for loop:

```
for i := 0; i < MaxOutstanding; i++ {
        clientRequests <- &Request{int32(i)}
}
```

Here is the working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Request struct {
    int32
}

var MaxOutstanding = 10

func handle(queue chan *Request, i int, done chan bool) {
    for r := range queue {
        fmt.Println(i, "---", r)
        done <- true
    }
}

func Serve(clientRequests chan *Request, quit, done chan bool) {
    // Start handlers
    for i := 0; i < MaxOutstanding; i++ {
        go handle(clientRequests, i, done)
    }
    <-quit // Wait to be told to exit.
}

func main() {
    clientRequests := make(chan *Request)
    quit := make(chan bool)
    done := make(chan bool)

    go Serve(clientRequests, quit, done)
    for i := 0; i < MaxOutstanding; i++ {
        clientRequests <- &Request{int32(i)}
    }

    fmt.Println("...........>", <-done)
    close(clientRequests)
    close(done)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/L5Y2YoFNvz

Comment: If I change the for loop in the main function to `for i := 0; i < 100; i++` I get the deadlock error - https://play.golang.org/p/rT2aa-sllX

Comment: I moved the code to drain up in the queue `done` up in the execution order and it seems to work fine. https://play.golang.org/p/UxCu1220--

Comment: @Pratyush:  doesn't really work with the final `<-done` at the end because you're racing another deadlock: https://play.golang.org/p/_hzsC3LKIs